# How to transfer all unique non key column records from a DynamoDB table to another new table?

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

A DynamoDB table has a non key column called Name

I want to be able to take all the unique Name from this table and populate a new table with just one column also Name (Partition Key).

My attempts with Lambda and DynamoDB Streams has been futile so far.

Can some one please guide me along the right path?

Comment: This is not related to your question but thought that it could be useful to know that most applications require only one DynamoDB table. They should be wide tables, meaning many columns or rather attributes as they say in the DynamoDB lingo. So if you copying data from a narrow table to another narrow table you probably should revisit your table design. Just a thought.

Comment: Yes it is schema less no SQL DB. But my use casew still stand. There are many applications for inter table transfers.... like Geo-replication etc... :)